# How can I solve this system of equation analytically?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
\begin{align}
i x'(t) &= c A(t)(e^{-i q(t)}) y(t)\\
i y'(t) &= c A(t)(e^{i q(t)}) x(t)\\
\\ 
A(t)&=a cos(wt-r)\\
q(t)&=b+dt+k sin(wt+r)
\end{align}
$$
where all of $a,b,c,d,k,w,r$ are constants ...
and the boundary condition is as follows:
$$
X(t=0)=1\\
Y(t=0)=0
$$
It might be possible to slightly simplify the solutions
by considering special cases. For example assume that
when one of the parameters of the theory, say $d$ has
some special values say $d_0=0$ or $1$ or something.
Then if in this case an analytical solution $x_0(t)$ and
$y_0(t)$ can be found, in the next step you may assume that
the solutions $x(t)=x_0(t)\cdot X(t)$ and $y(t)=y_0(t)\cdot Y(t)$.
Hopefully the equations for X(t) and Y(t) can be
much simpler??

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Pleae make sure I edited your question properly with MathJax. It greatly helps readability and is better to post them as such. Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot robjohn . You edited properly but what is $ in the second equation?

Comment: The parameter "rho" is in d. For example d=m*rho.

Comment: Can you just update the question to include that tidbit? $d=m*rho$. Regards